# ion-icons based on platform (does not work)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionicons

I'm making an Ionic/cordova app and I'm trying to use the Ionic icons. I notice that when using the 'ios' namings, it works perfectly but not when using the generic or md names. In those cases, no icon is visible.
I would like to have it automatically select the best icon per platform (what it should do according to the docs)

**Examples for the tabs**

I have this code for the first tab:

```
<ion-tab title="tab1" icon-off="ion-ios-list-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-list" href="#/tab/list">
(converts to <i class="icon ion-ios-list" ng-if="getIcon()" style=""></i>)
```

=> icon is visible

But when using the generic or material design names:

```
<ion-tab title="tab1" icon-off="ion-list" icon-on="ion-list" href="#/tab/list">
(converts to <i class="icon ion-list" ng-if="getIcon()"></i>    
or for md <i class="icon ion-md-list" ng-if="getIcon()" style=""></i>)
```

=> icon is missing

**Example for buttons**

`<button class="button button-icon ion-person-outline"></button>` => no icon
`<button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person-outline"></button>` => works
The behaviour is the same for other icons like barcode and list.

There's an exception that works without the ios, and that's the 'plus' icon:
`<button class="button button-icon ion-plus"></button>` => works! '
Strange enough, according to the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/) I should use `ion-add`, but that also gives no icon.

**Using ion-icon**

Using ion-icons gives me no icon at all (when I inspect the DOM, it shows also width and height are 0)
`<ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>` => no icon
`<ion-icon name="plus"></ion-icon>` => no icon

---

for reference, I'm using Visual Studio, 
Cordova CLI 6.2.0 and the file /css/ionic.app.css says 'Ionicons, v2.0.1'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What site are you gettin your ion icons from? As far as I understood, this one handles ionic 1.x http://ionicons.com/. And this one is for ionic v2 https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/. So as i remember when i was doing that, you cant mix them

Comment: Also, you haven't really posted an entire examples of how  you set an icon, but i recommend using an <i class>. See here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_icons.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I was using the Ionic 1 framework while the online documentation on the icons is for version 2. I'm migrating to v2 now.